# How to find the original (or oldest) version of a file on GitHub?

Tags: github

Given a file in a repository that might have been forked many a time, how would I go about searching for where it originally came from by searching the whole of GitHub, not just the current repository?

Specifically, I am looking at [this file](https://github.com/kipr/opencv/blob/master/modules/objdetect/src/featurepyramid.cpp) and would like to know where it originated as I want to track down the licence. I can perform this global search from the top page of https://github.com:

```
filename:featurepyramid.cpp fork:false
```

This returns 219 results, and there is no option to sort by "Earliest check-in date", which would at least get me some of the way to the answer. How can I get GitHub to help me narrow down my search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can view the history for a file directly through the link you posted (see attached image) or using git itself.  Here is the documentation for looking at file [history](https://help.github.com/articles/differences-between-commit-views/).

[image]

The History link leads to this [page](https://github.com/kipr/opencv/commits/master/modules/objdetect/src/featurepyramid.cpp)

And the first commit is [fbfccff](https://github.com/kipr/opencv/commit/fbfccffbaa04f2ac45c10d6d232bfb5caaf3c77c#diff-d25c7dd254e883e2529e1644782d5a76)